# Postgresql query for objects in nested JSONB field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-12

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6, and I have a table named  "ItemDbModel" with two columns looks like:

```
No integer,
Content jsonb
```

Say I put many records like:

```
 "No": 2, {"obj":"x","Item": {"Name": "BigDog", "Model": "NamedHusky", "Spec":"red dog"}}
 "No": 4, {"obj":"x","Item": {"Name": "MidDog", "Model": "NamedPeppy", "Spec":"no hair"}}
 "No": 5, {"obj":"x","Item": {"Name": "BigCat", "Model": "TomCat", "Spec":"blue color"}}
```

How can I query the table for:

1. Records where "Content.Item.Name" contains "Dog" **And** "Content.Item.Spec" contains "red".
2. Records where "Content.Item.Name" contains "Dog" **OR** "Content.Item.Spec" contains "red".
3. Records where **Any** json fields in "Content.Item" contains "dog".

And order by "Content.Item.Name.length"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 78):

You should become familiar with [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html).

```
-- #1
select *
from example
where content->'Item'->>'Name' ilike '%dog%'
and content->'Item'->>'Spec' ilike '%red%'

-- #2
select *
from example
where content->'Item'->>'Name' ilike '%dog%'
or content->'Item'->>'Spec' ilike '%red%'

-- #3
select distinct on(no) t.*
from example t,
lateral jsonb_each_text(content->'Item')
where value ilike '%dog%';

-- and
select *
from example t
order by length(content->'Item'->>'Name');
```

**Postgres 12** introduces new features implementing the SQL/JSON Path Language. Alternative queries using the `jsonpath` may look like this:

```
-- #1
select *
from example
where jsonb_path_exists(
    content, 
    '$ ? ($.Item.Name like_regex "dog" flag "i" && $.Item.Spec like_regex "red" flag "i")');

-- #2
select *
from example
where jsonb_path_exists(
    content, 
    '$ ? ($.Item.Name like_regex "dog" flag "i" || $.Item.Spec like_regex "red" flag "i")');

-- #3
select *
from example
where jsonb_path_exists(
    content, 
    '$.Item.* ? (@ like_regex "dog" flag "i")');
```

The first two queries are basically similar to the previous ones and the `->` syntax may seem simpler and more pleasant than `jsonpath` one. Particular attention should be paid to the third query, which uses a wildcard so it eliminates the need for using the expensive function `jsonb_each_text ()` and should be significantly faster.

Read in the documentation:

- [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)
- [jsonpath Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)

Comment: May I know how do we choose between '->' and '->>' ?

Comment: The `->` operator gives a json object, while `->>` yields text.

Comment: Disappointed in Postgres to be honest. These are unnecessarily confusing operators.

Comment: I know this is an old post. but what is the flag "i" supposed to mean

Comment: @jstuartmilne - `i` stands for case-insensitive match, see [9.15.2.2. Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) for details.

Comment: flawless answer @klin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995738/klin, I have data in josnb column like this in multiple rows: {"data": [{"pval": 0.7354, "Protein": "A0A0B4J2D5", "FoldChange": -0.1676, "MinusLog10p": 0.1334, "Significance": "Non-significant"}, {"pval": 0.0689, "Protein": "A0FGR8", "FoldChange": 2.5448, "MinusLog10p": 1.1615, "Significance": "Significant"}]}. I need to query across the column containing multiple records where a certain protein has a pval or FoldChange in a certain range. Can you kindly help?

Comment: @RanonKahn - there is no space in the comments to answer non-trivial questions. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @klin, I have asked the question in the forum. Eagerly looking forward to your response.