# Postgres and jsonb - search value at any key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is possible to look for a given value at any key in a JSONB column in Postgres? [In the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) I can't see any example.

Example value at a `JSONB` column:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

I want to find all records that have `1` as a value anywhere. NOTE: there may be other keys than `a, b, c` unknown at the moment.

Comment: top level? or anywhere deep?

Comment: can you post an example of your jsonb text?

Comment: @VaoTsun Top level

Comment: @McNets Question updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) value of `jsonb_each_text`, sample based on previous sample of McNets,:

```
t=# select * from json_test join jsonb_each_text(json_test.data) e on true 
where e.value = '1';
 id |                 data                 | key | value
----+--------------------------------------+-----+-------
  1 | {"a": 1}                             | a   | 1
  3 | {"a": 1, "b": {"c": "d", "e": true}} | a   | 1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe late, but it helped me:

```
with my_data(id, jdata) as (
values
    (1, '{ "a": 4, "b": 5}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{ "a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb),
    (3, '{ "x": {"y": 3, "z": 1}}'::jsonb),
    (4, '{ "a": [2,1,4]}'::jsonb),
    (5, '{ "a": [{"x": 2}, {"y": 1}, {"z": 2}]}'::jsonb)
)

select id, jdata
from my_data
where jdata @? '$.** ? (@ == 1)';

 id |           jdata           
----+---------------------------
  2 | { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
  3 | { "x": { "y": 3, "z": 1 } }
  4 | { "a": [2, 1, 4] }
  5 | { "a": [ { "x": 2 }, { "y": 1 }, { "z": 2 } ] }
(4 rows)
```

Comment: You should add, that this requires Postgres 12 as the SQL JSON/Path operators were introduced in that version

Comment: It worked greatly but it is case sensitive. How to change to case insensitive?

Comment: I found it: where jdata @? '$.** ? (@ like_regex 1 flag "i")' 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130740/postgresql-query-for-objects-in-nested-jsonb-field

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_each_text()`:

```
with my_data(id, jdata) as (
values
    (1, '{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::json),
    (2, '{ "j": 4, "k": 5, "l": 6}'::json),
    (3, '{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}'::json)
)

select id, jdata
from my_data,
lateral json_each_text(jdata) 
where value::int = 1

 id |           jdata           
----+---------------------------
  1 | { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
  3 | { "x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
(2 rows)
```