# Use variables as search keys within jsonb_extract_path

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I'm working on an event that compares the jsonb values within a column between the last entry and the new entry. I have another table that defines what values to compare by passing on a jsonb object itself. What I'm working with goes something like this:

```
select jsonb_extract_path(_tmp_jsonb, 'key_1', 'key2') into target;
```

and the jsonb object I'm looking inside is this:

```
{
 "key1": {"key2": 15},
 "key3": {"key2": {"key4": 25}}
}
```

Now I can get 15 with the above command no problem, but what I'd like to do is be able pass any key combinations as a jsonb array like `{"search_keys":["key3", "key2", "key4"]}`. So something like this:

```
select jsonb_extract_path(_tmp_jsonb, ["key3", "key2", "key4"]) into target;
```

More clearly, what I'm asking is how to use variable length argument arrays in postgres, as you would do in python with *args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the `#>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) instead of the function. The right operand is a text array.

```
declare
    _tmp_jsonb jsonb;
    _path text[];
    target jsonb;
begin
    _tmp_jsonb := '{"key1": {"key2": 15}, "key3": {"key2": {"key4": 25}}}';
    _path := array['key3', 'key2', 'key4'];
    target := _tmp_jsonb #> _path;
    ...
```

By the way, do not use `select` for simple assignments, it is too costly.

In **Postgres 12** you can use SQL/JSON path functions, e.g.:

```
declare
    _tmp_jsonb jsonb;
    _path jsonpath; -- !!
    target jsonb;
begin
    _tmp_jsonb := '{"key1": {"key2": 15}, "key3": {"key2": {"key4": 25}}}';
    _path := '$.key3.key2.key4';
    target := jsonb_path_query(_tmp_jsonb, _path);
    ...
```

The new feature is flexible and powerful as a json path may contain wildcards and supports recursion.

Read in the documentation:

- [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)
- [jsonpath Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)

See also `jsonpath` examples in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131222/1995738)

Comment: Nice, now is there any way I can also have a wildcard key?

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. Although I'm not sure if we could bump up to Postgres12.