# Postgresql - querying jsonb throws a syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has a column `data` of `jsonb` type.

```
create table event
(
    id             bigserial
        primary key,
    created_at     timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
    type           text                                   not null,
    created_by     text,
    data           jsonb,
    event_time     timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);
```

In that field I am saving a json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "comment": "Changed by recipient",
  "source": "Recipient page"
}
```

I would like to query values in that table by the value of the `comment` property of the `data` json object. Something like this in based by examples [here][1]:

```
select * from event
where type = 'pickup-data-changed' 
  and data -> 'comment' = 'Changed by recipient'
```

If I query like that I get an invalid token error:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "Changed" is invalid. Position: 104
```

What am I doing wrong here?
If I do it as a double arrow like suggested in the comments:

```
select * from event
    where type = 'pickup-data-changed' 
      and data ->-> 'comment' = 'Changed by recipient'
```

I get an error:

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb ->-> unknown Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I make this query work?
[1]: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-query-a-postgres-jsonb-column-1433

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql query for objects in nested JSONB field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130740/postgresql-query-for-objects-in-nested-jsonb-field)

Comment: You need `->>` not `->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get an invalid token error. What am I doing wrong here?

`data -> 'comment'` returns a value of type `jsonb`, so the right hand side of the comparison `'Changed by recipient'` is parsed as JSON as well - and it's invalid JSON. To create a JSON string value to compare against, you'd need to write

```
… data -> 'comment' = '"Changed by recipient"'
```

> If I do it as a double arrow like suggested in the comments, `data ->-> 'comment'`

The comments suggested

```
… data ->> 'comment' = 'Changed by recipient'
```

not `->->`.

Answer (score 0):

alternatives:

```
select * from event
where type = 'pickup-data-changed'
  and data -> 'comment' = '"Changed by recipient"'::jsonb;
```

or

```
select * from event
where type = 'pickup-data-changed'
  and data['comment'] = '"Changed by recipient"'::jsonb;
```